# MaterialBetterSpinner validations

Tags: java, android, validation, android-spinner

I'm using `MaterialBetterSpinner` library to display list of Areas in my app. I want to validate `MaterialBetterSpinner` if the user has selected the `Area` from the list or not, and display the error if he has not selected.

I am trying to achieve this with the code below, but it doesn't work.

```
    MaterialBetterSpinner spArea = (MaterialBetterSpinner) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_area);
    spArea.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            spArea.setError("Please select an Area from list");
        }
    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check by default item is selected at 0 index in spinner

Comment: @Piyush: thank you. Can you help me with some example

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
if(spArea.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
     spArea.setError("Please select an Area from list");
}
```